# How to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 with dual boot through a virtual drive created upon win 7

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

It may sound a dumb question but I really need your suggestion in it.I have a pc having windows 7 in it .I just downloaded an ISO file of Ubuntu 14.04.1 (the latest one) .the problem is that my DVD drive has lost its capability of writing the DVD .so I have two options first that I make a bootable pen drive with this iso file and use it ,but when I try to do so I feel confused because after initializing the installation it asks for having a installation drive in DVD so how am I capable of installing Ubuntu dual boot anyway .I have heard that there is an option of creating a virtual DVD drive and using it for installation or boot purpose.but I don't know how to create a bootable virtual drive to have a dual boot of Ubuntu inside windows 7.treat me as a novice in this regard ,so can someone please suggest me how to do it in a simple step by step manner? thanks !

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a problem with creating a bootable flash drive. I just did an install of 14.04 this week with a flash drive, and I did not get such problems. I used a tool called Rufus: http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: @AlexYan I already told you that my DVD writer not working so how can i make bootable ISO with Rufus??

Comment: "I just did an install of 14.04 this week with a flash drive, and I did not get such problems. I used a tool called Rufus". I used Rufus to make a flash drive. Not a DVD... At no point at all did I mention the letters "DVD"...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep your existing os which is win7 in your case, make a space (it's up to you) for ubuntu installation via diskmgmt.msc (run it as admin). shrink volume and you can leave it unformatted

use [universal usb installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create a bootable usb with your iso

boot up to live usb and within your installation chose something else ([how to use something else](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)) complete your installation.

restart into ubuntu live cd again (it might not be necessary but i do it anyways)

repair windows boot with [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

it should work just fine

you can comment for further support...